# JavaScript: assign ID to a tag with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have some html like this:

```
<p class="paragraph">Some paragraph text</p>
<p class="dummy">Some dummy text</p>
<p class="paragraph">Some more paragraph text</p>
```

How could I add IDs only to `<p>` tags with `paragraph` class using JS or jQuery?

So that the result would look like this

```
<p class="paragraph" id="paragraph">Some paragraph text</p>
<p class="dummy">Some dummy text</p>
<p class="paragraph" id="paragraph">Some more paragraph text</p>
```

for the browser?

I **know** each ID should ne unique but in my particular case it doesn't matter.

Comment: id should be unique.

Comment: Why do you want to have multiple elements with the same ID? IDs are supposed to be unique and you are going to run into issues if you try to use the IDs for something.

Comment: *"So that the result would look like this"* That would be making a valid document **invalid**. You can't (validly) have the same ID on more than one element.

Comment: See above re: unique IDs. Maybe edit your question to describe what you're actually trying to accomplish. As well as what you've tried.

Comment: Separately: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? There's a ***lot*** of information on the web, including here on SO, about how to A) Select elements, B) Go through that selection, and C) Set properties on them.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish but if you're looking to attach some sort of data to tags with a paragraph class, you could use the data attribute like: `data-category="paragraph"`. You could add that dynamically.

Comment: I know that but in my case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Guys, instead of teaching me obvious things, dropping my weak reputation or sending me to google, please answer my question or just ignore it.

Seems you all have forgotten that Stack Network is a place for questions and answers, but not a place for showing yourself off and offering to find the answer on one's own.

Answer (score 1):

DIVs should have unique IDs to have valid syntax. While the page will load correctly with duplicate IDs, you will run into issue when referencing an element *by* that duplicate ID.

There should never be an instance where you would need to do this. They question is really what you're trying to accomplish *by* giving them uniqe IDs, as there is likely a better way. For example, changing display for each class:

```
$('.paragraph').css('display', 'none');
```

If you really want to give them IDs, what you should do is generate them *uniquely* with code similar to the following:

```
$('.paragraph').each(function(i) {
    $(this).prop('id', 'paragraph' + i);
});
```

You can then call a specific paragraph with `$('#paragraph2')`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Better use `prop`. Or even vanilla-js, it's cleaner.

Comment: You could lose `new_id` altogether and just do `$('.paragraph').each(function(i) {` and `'paragraph' + i`. Not that it's any remarkable improvement, but just seems cleaner to me. [**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/0qjgm058/)

Comment: @Santi -- Yes, I really should have thought of that. Updating now to match :)